# Restrict resizable working only within a specified div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery's resizable. Is it possible to restrict resizing within a specified div? maxwidth, maxheight would not work because I'm looking for a way to restrict resizing within a div.

```
$('#elastic').resizable({
     handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw',
     aspectRatio: true,
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI has got the [`containment` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-containment) which can be set to `parent`.

```
$('#elastic').resizable({
     handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw',
     aspectRatio: true,
     containment: "parent"
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/1hzr2f1c/